# CakePHP3 - How to change the Pagination url

Tags: url, cakephp, pagination

My url is mapped, for example:
`localhost/seo-url/seo-variable`

Url if not mapped looks like this:
`localhost/controller-name/index/2`

```
$routes->connect('/seo-url/:product_id',[,'controller' => 'ControllerNames', 'action' => 'index','product_id' => null],['pass' => [product_id'],'product_id' => '[a-z0-9\-_]+']); ------- CakePHP 3.1 v
```

Pagination links are wrong and look like this:

```
localhost/controller-name/index/seo-variable?page=1
localhost/controller-name/index/seo-variable?page=2
localhost/controller-name/index/seo-variable?page=3
```

I tried this, but unfortunately it did not help:

```
<?php $this->Paginator->options(['url' => ['controller' => 'ControllerNames', 'action' => 'index', 'product_id' => $product->id]]); ?>
```

The result was wrong:

```
localhost:9080/controller-name?page=1&product_id=2<br>
localhost:9080/controller-name?page=2&product_id=2<br>
localhost:9080/controller-name?page=3&product_id=2<br>
```

**What I need to change that links correctly displayed?**
***Solution A***

```
localhost/seo-url/seo-variable?page=1
localhost/seo-url/seo-variable?page=2
localhost/seo-url/seo-variable?page=3
```

OR
***Solution B***

```
localhost/controller-name/index/2?page=1
localhost/controller-name/index/2?page=2
localhost/controller-name/index/2?page=3
```

My English is bad, but I hope you understand what I want.

Comment: You should also post your routes.php content. Looks like you got it configured wrongly, otherwise it would work as expected. Also always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Comment: Not here as comment, in your post (edited).

Comment: I am unsure what you should change exactly in your code, but you can change your paginator options like in here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html, by using something like $this->paginator->options(['url' => $someOptions]);

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately without success